# Need to .gitignore a certain file in multiple subdirectories

Tags: git, github

I have the following .csv file in 4 subdirectories within one main directory.  The path to each .csv file that I want to ignore is the following:

```
Mood/High/Input_File/removeThis.csv
Mood/Low/Input_File/removeThis.csv
Mood/Mania/Input_File/removeThis.csv
Mood/Depres/Input_File/removeThis.csv
```

I placed this in my .gitignore file, but it did not work:

```
/Mood/**/**/removeThis.csv
```

I do NOT want to remove ALL of the .csv files in my input_file folder however, so I'm a bit stuck on how to remove just this file in all of the subdirectories.  Thank you.

Comment: Note that `**` means *any number of directories*. So `**/**` means *any number of directories, followed by any number of directories* and is at best redundant (though if "any number" means "1 or more" you now have a "two or more" setup). Still, that should have worked: you might want to add why you don't think it's working (e.g., output from `git status`).

Answer (score 0):

`.gitignore` works recursively. You can simply have this in your `.gitignore` file

```
removeThis.csv
```